# Redirect script for mobile phone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, redirect

I'm looking for a simple redirect from the user to a different URL when the screen or window width is lower then 500px.

I don't do want to use "User Agent" either because I think it is less reliable in the long run and I don't want keep updating this.

This is the script I found on the internet but for some reason it keeps redirecting between the 2 websites.
The resolution of samsung is 320px x 533px

On a normal pc it works when you resize the window, on Firefox and Internet Explorer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load resize',function(){
       if($(window).width() > 500){
       window.location = "http://www.website.com";
       }
   });
</script>
```

and on the other website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load resize',function(){
       if($(window).width() < 500){
       window.location = "http://mobiel.website.com";
       }
   });
</script>
```